# Почему как бы подключается тоесть когда делаю чтото не так то выдаёт ошибку но по факту не работает Echo не выводится

Tags: php, классы

Пытаюсь использовать namespaces в php, написал следующих 2 файла, но нет никаких ошибок и `echo` не срабатывает

App.php

```php
<?php
namespace shop\core;

class App { 
  public function _construct(){
    echo 'Privet';
  }   
}
```

index.php

```php
<?php
  require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/init.php';

  new \shop\core\App();
?>
```

Comment: к сожалению, не понятно ничего(((

Comment: Сформулируйте свой вопрос по другому

Comment: что находится в файле `/config/init.php`?

Comment: Спасибо большое мне уже помогли

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не выводится потому что для функции-конструктора используется **ДВА!!!** подчеркивания, а у вас одно. Вместо конструктора вы создали обычную функцию, которая не выполняется сама по себе при создании экземпляра объекта

> https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php